# Dynamic Text : Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, dynamic-text

I am  trying to create a movie clip where I have a dynamic text with a default caption "Sound '#'".I am trying to make it dynamic and the character '#' should be replaced with any alphabets. I am trying to read the text in the dynamic text and I am replacing the letter with another letter using the replace function in Action Script 3.0. When I used trace to check, the letters are replaced but it is not displaying in the flash stage. To my surprise it only displayes the uppercase letters. Here is the code..

```
    var myPattern:RegExp = /#/g; 
    myTxt = myTxt.replace(myPattern,"w");
    trace(myTxt); // displays the expected output in the output panel
    movieclip1.myTxt.text=myTxt;
    trace(movieclip1.myTxt.text); // displays the expected output in the output panel
```

But when I test the movie the replayed letter is missing. Any ideas?

Thanks,
H

Comment: are you using a specific font?

Comment: are you sure the textfield is not restricted?

Comment: No I am using the default font. The textfield restriction ? how do I set that. As I had mentioned when I use a upper case character it works. Like it displays "Sound 'W'".

Comment: ok I got it. I opened the properties panel and clicked on embed fonts options and checked :All glyphs under character ranges and it worked. But I am not sure what it exactly does and why do we need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it. I opened the properties panel and clicked on embed fonts options and checked :All glyphs under character ranges and it worked. But I am not sure what it exactly does and why do we need that.